# How Spring Data Neo4j does choose the type of the transaction (Placebo or TopLevel)

Tags: transactions, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a method which should create a sub-graph defined this way:

```
public Post createAndLink(Appuser appuser, Post post, String linkTo) {
    Transaction tx = template.getGraphDatabaseService().beginTx();
    Post savedPost = null;
    if(post != null && appuser != null){

        post.setCreatedBy(appuser);
        if(post.getId() == null && post.getId() == ""){
            post.setId("IND"+GenerateUUID.getUUID());
        }
        System.out.println(">>> Id created : "+post.getId());

        //Date check
        String d = post.getDate();
        if(d != null && d.length() == 11 && ConversionUtils.isNumeric(d.substring(0, 4))
                && ConversionUtils.isNumeric(d.substring(5, 7)) && ConversionUtils.isNumeric(d.substring(8, 10))){
            if(!ConversionUtils.isPastDate(d)){
                System.out.println("Cannot save post with date after today");
                return null;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(">>> Date created : "+post.getDate());

        //People check
        Set<People> people = new HashSet<People>();
        if(post.getPeople() != null){
            for(People p : post.getPeople()){
                People pFromDb = peopleService.findById(p.getId());
                people.add(pFromDb != null ? pFromDb : new People("PPL"+GenerateUUID.getUUID(), p.getName()));
            }
            post.setPeople(people);
        }
        System.out.println(">>> People created : "+post.getPeople());

        //Place check
        if(post.getPlace() != null){
            Place pFromDb = placeService.findById(post.getPlace().getId());
            post.setPlace(pFromDb != null ? pFromDb : new Place(post.getPlace().getId()));
        }

        System.out.println(">>> Place created : "+post.getPlace());

        System.out.println("Post checking OK.");

        savedPost = repository.findById(linkTo);

        if(savedPost != null){
            Set<Post> linked = new HashSet<Post>();
            linked.add(savedPost);
            post.setLinkedPosts(linked);
        }
        template.save(post);

        System.out.println("=====> [saveWithUser]: Saved OK!");
        tx.success();
        tx.close();
    }

    return savedPost;
}
```

I removed all @Transactional annotations and transaction blocs from my service methods (controllers and repositories are not marked as Transactional).

Now, when I call this method from a controller A, the tx is of type Placebo. When I call it from a controller B, the tx type is a TopLevel.

I even made a test with calling the controller A method from the controller B (like in the example below) and it worked perfectly (with a TopLevel Tx). When I do the opposite way, the Tx is Placebo.

**Controller A:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newandlinksimilar/{linkedTo}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody boolean createAndLinkNewSimilar(@RequestBody Post post, @PathVariable String linkedTo){
        Post created = null;
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (post!= null && !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            AppuserDetails userDetails = (AppuserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();
            Appuser currentUser = appuserService.findByLogin(userDetails.getUsername());
            created = postService.createAndLinkSimilar(currentUser, post, linkedTo);
        }
       return created;
}
```

**Controller B:**

```
@autowired
private ControllerA controllerA;

@RequestMapping("/init")
public ModelAndView init(){
    //I create a new Post object "post" with dummy data
    controllerA.createAndLinkSimilar(post,"XXXXXX");
    //Or postService.createAndLinkSimilar(appuser,post,"XXXXXX");
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

Both tests are made from a GUI ajax call to the controller method.

I can't understand when and how Spring choose the type of the transaction?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placebo transactions are nested transactions in Neo4j, they are created when there is already a top-level transaction running, and only affect the top-level transaction when they are:

- not finished
- rolled back
- terminated

So somehow (perhaps some open-transaction-in-view automatism) already creates a top-level tx in your application around your first controller (A) or something you call before, like your service doesn't finish it's transactions correctly, so they are still running.

Perhaps you have an early return somewhere without calling close.

I also recommend to use the try-with-resource pattern, which closes the transaction automatically at the end of the block, otherwise do `close` in `finally`.

```
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
   ... your database code ...
   tx.success()
}
```

Comment: Really weird!!
As you can see, I have no Transactions in the controller.
I tried to add a new Transaction at the beginning of the controller. Its type was also Placebo.
This controller is the entry point so it should be the one that should be executed :/
And For sure I've restarted the webserver.

Could it be because of a lost file somewhere in my db?

Comment: What does `appuserService.findByLogin` do?

Comment: @Override
public Appuser findByLogin(String login) {
 return repository.findByLogin(login);
}

And the repository method : 
@Query("MATCH (u:Appuser) WHERE u.login = {0} return u")
public Appuser findByLogin(String login);

Comment: Perhaps you can expose a small unit test that exposes this behavior, I have note see it myself before so can't reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I found that I'm not closing properly a transaction in another method (to fetch other data).